# Вернуть самое большое число

Tags: sql, max

Задание: Выбрать список самых дорогих моделей автомобилей каждого бренда. Есть по две машины каждой марки, нужно, чтобы выводилось по самой дорогой из каждой, то есть, должно быть выведено 6 машин.

Выводимые поля: `BrandName, AutoModel, Price`

Отношения:

[image: Диаграмма]
[image: Список машин]

```
SELECT
BrandName,
AutoModel,
MAX(Auto.Price) as 'Стоимость'
FROM Brand JOIN Auto ON (Brand.BrandID = Auto.BrandID) 
GROUP BY Auto.BrandID
ORDER BY MAX(Auto.Price) DESC
```

Если убрать `BrandName`, `AutoModel`, то все работает, он находит самое большое число в каждой марке, как вывести необходимые столбы? Ругается, пишет:

> Столбец "Brand.BrandName" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не
>   содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Comment: вам нужно вывести самую дорогую машину для каждой марки?

Comment: @Данил Все верно.

Comment: @Данил за год армии -_- по вылетало из головы все.

Answer (score 1):

Если чётко две машины каждой марки - вот так должно работать (проверял)

```
SELECT t1.*, brands.BrandName 
FROM Auto t1 
JOIN Auto t2 ON (t1.brandID = t2.brandID AND t1.price > t2.price) 
JOIN Brands on (t1.BrandID = Brands.BrandID)
```

Но если не две модели в марке, а, скажем, три - сорри. Но может, от моего варианта можно как-то оттолкнуться...

Comment: не ну количество может у каждой марки быть разное, я для удобства сейчас сделал по две.

Comment: Я сделал всё, что мог. Мозги вскипели, иду пар стравливать...

Comment: Вот и у меня. Несколько часов ломаю голову. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А так у вас рабочий вариант. Если машин только две

Answer (score 1):

Если не предполагается несколько машин одной марки с одинаковой максимальной ценой тогда можно вот так:

```
select
  b.BrandName, 
  a.AutoModel, 
  a.Price
from (
  select 
    a.BrandId,
    max(a.Price) as Price
  from    
    Auto a   
  group by
    a.BrandId  
) agr 
join Auto a on agr.BrandId = a.BrandId and agr.Price = a.Price
join Brand b on a.BrandId = b.BrandId
```

Comment: Недопустимое имя объекта Auto

Comment: Наоборот так и должно работать, чтобы можно и 2 машины с одинаковой ценой от 1 бренда вывести. Круто, не знал, что можно селектить из селекта. 
@ne0n всё работает, перепроверьте

Comment: @ne0n это имя таблицы с машинами, она у вас создана?

Comment: @Данил это называется подзапрос, вообще sql штука могучая там много чего есть)

Comment: @tsybin_na да. У меня две таблицы Brand и Auto

Comment: у меня этих таблиц нет, я не проверял, но у автора все норм, может быть вы их в другой схеме создали?

Comment: @tsybin_na наоборот автор он)) ну подзапросы я знал в выражениях where, но не from

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
select distinct 
BrandName,
MAX(Price)
from Brand 
inner join Auto on Brand.BrandID = Auto.BrandID
group by BrandName
order by MAX(Price) DESC
```

Comment: не верно же, он не выводит название авто, да и ваш запрос аналогичен этому
select
    b_name,
    MAX(Auto.price)
from Brand
         inner join Auto on Brand.b_id = Auto.b_id
group by b_name;

Comment: хотя бы так. Не знаю как вывести столбец с моделью.