# SQL определить марку автомобиля с самой высокой средней стоимостью автомобилей этой марки

Tags: sql, max

Имеется 12 авто по 2 на Марку, надо найти среднюю стоимость (Price) каждой марки и вывести марку с максимальным значением.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгруппируй по бренду и получи средние по маркам - результат отсортируй по убыванию и возьми первую строку.

SELECT TOP 1 Brands.BrandName, AVG(Auto.Price) 
FROM brands 
JOIN Auto ON  (Brand.BrandID = Auto.BrandID)
GROUB BY brands.BrandName
ORDER BY AVG(Auto.Price)  DESC

Как-то так. Не могу проверить в MS SQL.

Comment: Все верно, спасибо дружище. Только ТОР 1 пишется после селекта ♥

Comment: Может подскажешь здесь. Буду признателен. 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088220/sql-server-самое-большое-число

Comment: ==Только ТОР 1 пишется после селект== Подзабыл MS :) Сейчас поправлю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088220/sql-server-самое-большое-число
Можешь глянуть пожалуйста ☺

Comment: Уже смотрю. Пока идей нет